# Is it possible to have knockoutjs update the 'initialdata' object?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel, knockout.js

Here's a much simplified example of what I'm trying to do with knockoutjs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var derp = { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 };

            window.onload = function() { go(); }

            function go()
            {
                var ViewModel = function(foobar)
                {
                    this.foo = ko.observable(foobar.foo);
                    this.bar = ko.observable(foobar.bar);
                }

                ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(derp));
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input data-bind="value: foo"/>
        <input data-bind="value: bar"/>
        <button onclick="go();">Go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The objective of this code is to have knockoutjs to update the the values in `derp`, not the copy inside of the ViewModel.

Is there a way to accomplish this easily with knockout, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**Edit for context:**

This is culled from a much larger application.  My intent was to use knockout to display and edit the properties of a large, wooly, javascript object.  These objects are instantiated dynamically by the user, and can be switched between at-will.

Before I found found knockout, I was manually created DOM elements to do the displaying and editing of each object which was messy and cumbersome.  I have some experience with MVVM via WPF in C#, and would have much preferred to use that approach.  My initial understanding of knockout was that it'd do just that, not realizing that the ViewModel copies the values captured by `ko.observable`*.  The ViewModel still has a use for me, as it allows me to conditionally expose and simplify access to the members I'd like to edit.

Comment: I am just curious to the why you would try to use knockoutjs and not want to use the model.  I mean you can just use normal javascript to modify the original derp ob, but I dont think I fully understand why you are trying to work around ko.js.  Maybe I need more context of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll edit the question to add some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do like @Etch response with `Save` method. This helps a lot.
But if You want to automate such a things, then I would go with `subscribe` on observables.

Maybe it's not a cleaner way to do this. Would be more happy if I'm were able to pass variable by reference.

I've prefer to use some wrapper around observables to type less:

```js
var returnFireObservable = function(variable, property) {
    var obs = ko.observable(variable[property]);
    obs.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        variable[property] = newValue;
    });
    return obs;
};
```

And use in code this way:

```js
var ViewModel = function(foobar) {
    this.foo = returnFireObservable (foobar, "foo");
    this.bar = returnFireObservable (foobar, "bar");
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(derp));
```

Little demo http://jsfiddle.net/AlfeG/eQ9Zf/2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does indeed help.  This looks like a good compromise given that  it looks like I'm trying to make knockout do something it wasn't designed for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I fully understand what you want, but I will take a crack at it.

You have defined your model as so:

```js
var ViewModel = function(foobar)
            {
                this.foo = ko.observable(foobar.foo);
                this.bar = ko.observable(foobar.bar);
            }
```

you initialized your knockout model with  `var derp = { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 };` aka lotsmorecomplicatedobject.

So your inputs will get those values due to the `data-bind` tag.  You then modify those input values then hit the save button and want to update your original javascript object.

If that is the case I would lean towards this...

Change your viewModel to this:

```js
var ViewModel = function(foobar)
                {

                    this.foo = ko.observable(foobar.foo);
                    this.bar = ko.observable(foobar.bar);
                    save: function() { derp.foo = this.foo;
                                       derp.bar = this.bar;          
                        //  ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { obj1: this.foo, obj2: this.bar });
                    }
                }
```

And then change your button click event to:  `ViewModel.save();`

I added the postJson object as an example because this is how I handle that type of data.  I look at the variable you pass into the initial `ViewModel` definition as just that..  Here is my data that I want to pre-populate my viewmodel from and from that point forward I use my ViewModel for everything.  Once you take that mindset you dont have a need to update the original object.

Comment: I apologize for the misleading term "initial data"; that terminology is used in the knockout examples, and I thought that would help clarify things.  I agree that initializing a `ViewModel` and never looking back is the way to go, but my real "initial data" is a complicated javascript object generated by a different library.  Other parts of the project rely on it heavily, so I cannot abandon it so easily.

Comment: I dont know, I think initial data is exactly how Knockoutjs treats it and why the terminology on thier site is as so.  If the javascript must persist, just use the save method to persist the viewmodel values to your original object.  I think @AlfeG has another good alternative.